# How is str implemented in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-internals

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.getsizeof("")
40
```

Why does the empty string use so many bytes? Does anybody know what is stored in those 40 bytes?

Comment: string is an object in python, objects have attributes.

Comment: which attributes has str?

Comment: also it depends on your system ... mine only says 24 for `""`

Comment: Mine is 37. Interesting, indeed. Can someone explain why is it so ? (Python version 2.7.3)

Comment: dir(str) does not show only attributes belongs to the objects it also show class attributes and methods - that doesnt need additional memory from object. So please give me example of one attribute that needs memory....

Comment: @user2221720 the length of the string, maybe reference count, ...

Comment: `sys.getsizeof(o)` just calls `o.__sizeof__()`. The implementation for a string object is [here](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/687295c6c8f2/Objects/stringobject.c#l3572).

Comment: @Aya and adds some garbage collector overhead to it: http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/6110ed94f86d/Python/sysmodule.c#l860

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Well, not necessarily. `sys.getsizeof('') == ''.__sizeof__()` returns `True`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Python strings are objects, so that values is the size of the object itself. So this size will always be bigger than the string size itself.

From `stringobject.h`:

```c
typedef struct {
    PyObject_VAR_HEAD
    long ob_shash;
    int ob_sstate;
    char ob_sval[1];

    /* Invariants:
     *     ob_sval contains space for 'ob_size+1' elements.
     *     ob_sval[ob_size] == 0.
     *     ob_shash is the hash of the string or -1 if not computed yet.
     *     ob_sstate != 0 iff the string object is in stringobject.c's
     *       'interned' dictionary; in this case the two references
     *       from 'interned' to this object are *not counted* in ob_refcnt.
     */
} PyStringObject;
```

From here you can get some clues on how those bytes are used:

- `len(str)+1` bytes to store the string itself;
- 8 bytes for the hash;
- (...)

Comment: Oddly enough, a C program which just prints `sizeof(PyStringObject)` says it's `40`, but `sys.getsizeof('')` returns only `37`.

Comment: No matter. There's a comment in the source code: "Using `PyStringObject_SIZE` instead of `sizeof(PyStringObject)` saves 3 bytes per string allocation on a typical system."

Answer (score 3):

You can find some information about the implementation if python strings in a [weblog article by Laurent Luce](http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/python-string-objects-implementation/). Additionally you can browse the [source](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Objects/stringobject.c).

The size of string objects depends on the OS and type of machine and some choices. On 64-bit FreeBSD, using unicode for string literals (`from __future__ import unicode_literals`):

```
In [1]: dir(str)
Out[1]: ['__add__', '__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__doc__',
 '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', 
'__getnewargs__', '__getslice__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__le__', 
'__len__', '__lt__', '__mod__', '__mul__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', 
'__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__rmod__', '__rmul__', '__setattr__', 
'__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '_formatter_field_name_split', 
'_formatter_parser', 'capitalize', 'center', 'count', 'decode', 'encode', 
'endswith', 'expandtabs', 'find', 'format', 'index', 'isalnum', 'isalpha', 
'isdigit', 'islower', 'isspace', 'istitle', 'isupper', 'join', 'ljust', 
'lower', 'lstrip', 'partition', 'replace', 'rfind', 'rindex', 'rjust', 
'rpartition', 'rsplit', 'rstrip', 'split', 'splitlines', 'startswith', 'strip', 
'swapcase', 'title', 'translate', 'upper', 'zfill']

In [2]: import sys

In [3]: sys.getsizeof("")
Out[3]: 52

In [4]: sys.getsizeof("test")
Out[4]: 68

In [7]: sys.getsizeof("t")
Out[7]: 56

In [8]: sys.getsizeof("te")
Out[8]: 60

In [9]: sys.getsizeof("tes")
Out[9]: 64
```

Every character uses 4 bytes extra in this case.

Answer (score 1):

It gives the object size of str class with empty value,
when doing such things `sys.getsizeof("")` it actually creates a string class object which have many attributes, and then calculate the size of that object.
It is equal to,

```
x = str()
sys.getsizeof(x)  #in my environment it prints 37
```

Then for each char it takes 1 byte

```
x = "r"
sys.getsizeof(x)  #prints 38
x = "ros"
sys.getsizeof(x)  #prints 40
```